# Erro ao importar Serviço da NFSe de Aracaju

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, visual-studio-2013

Estou tentando adicionar esse serviço no VS 2013:

`https://www3.webiss.com.br/aracajuse_wsnfse/NfseServices.svc`

Mas não é possível adicionar essa URL como serviço. Normalmente as URL's que adiciono não possuem o **.svc** no final.

Erro:

> There was an error downloading 'https://www3.webiss.com.br/aracajuse_wsnfse/NfseServices.svc?wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>
> The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

Tentei adicionar tanto como Serviço e como WebReference, mas nenhuma funciona.

Comment: A URL não é `https://www3.webiss.com.br/aracajuse_wsnfse/NfseServices.svc?wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc`?

Comment: Mesmo erro, eu tinha tentado com essa também. Outra coisa que tentei foi adicionar `?wsdl` no final da URL mas ainda continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: Tu tem algum certificado digital válido instalado na máquina?

Comment: Tenho um certificado, vence mês que vem, selecionei ele para ao inserir a URL.

Comment: Verifique data e hora do computador, confira com a hora do seu celular para ser mais preciso. @NickeManarin

Comment: @HStackOverflow Tudo sincronizado. Verificado com um relógio online.

Comment: @NickeManarin '.svc' é WCF(Windows Communication Foundation).
Dê uma olhada aqui.
http://www.devmedia.com.br/wcf-windows-communication-foundation-parte-001-criando-o-servico/18137

Comment: @Marconi Estou tentando consumir um serviço de terceiros. Vou conseguir um outro certificado para fazer mais testes. É o jeito.

Comment: @NickeManarin da uma olhada no tutorial que dexei pra vc. Acho que pode te ajudar.Ow então procure ler sobre WCF.

Comment: @NickeManarin Uma pergunta super boba. Você têm acesso a este serviço? Pelo pouco que eu sei com algumas coisas pequenas que faço a cerca de notas fiscais dos estados, você necessita de uma certificação que funcione propriamente, sem uma certificação você não terá acesso com a prefeitura e dará o retorno 403, ou seja, a falta de credencial. Verifique o certificado que é certo de ser este o problema.

Comment: Faz tempo que tive esse problema, mas se eu me lembro corretamente, eu tinha um certificado de Aracaju, mas agora não lembro se era válido na época. Acabei desistindo pois o cliente acabou não aceitando. Na época eu já tinha conhecimento sobre isso, pois eu trabalhava com outros estados com a NF-e. ;)